Creating sortable table with react is not working
The first part include passing the items of the table to useSortableData function, as well as config variable which determine the sort order.
const useSortableData = (items, config = null) => {
      const [sortConfig, setSortConfig] = React.useState(config);
    
      const sortedItems = React.useMemo(() => {
        let sortableItems = [items];
        console.log(sortableItems);
        if (sortConfig !== null) {
          sortableItems.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a[sortConfig.key] < b[sortConfig.key]) {
              return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? -1 : 1;
            }
            if (a[sortConfig.key] > b[sortConfig.key]) {
              return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? 1 : -1;
            }
            return 0;
          });
        }
        return sortableItems;
      }, [items, sortConfig]);
    
      const requestSort = (key) => {
        let direction = 'ascending';
        if (
          sortConfig &&
          sortConfig.key === key &&
          sortConfig.direction === 'ascending'
        ) {
          direction = 'descending';
        }
        setSortConfig({ key, direction });
      };
    
      return { items: sortedItems, requestSort, sortConfig };
    };

The second part
const ProductTable = (products) => {
      const { items, requestSort, sortConfig } = useSortableData(products);
      console.log(items);
      const getClassNamesFor = (name) => {
        if (!sortConfig) {
          return;
        }
        return sortConfig.key === name ? sortConfig.direction : undefined;
      };
      return (
        <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="py-4">
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => requestSort('symbol')}
                className={getClassNamesFor('symbol')}
              >
              Symbol
              </button>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="py-4">
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => requestSort('beta')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('beta')}
            >
              Beta
            </button>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="py-4">
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => requestSort('volAvg')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('volAvg')}
            >
              Average Volume
            </button>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="py-4">
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => requestSort('mktCap')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('mktCap')}
            >
              Market Cap
            </button>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <tr key={item.symbol}>
            <td>{item.beta}</td>
            <td>{item.volAvg}</td>
            <td>{item.mktCap}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
      );
    };

Finally,
<ProductTable products={
          store.stocks.map((stock) => {
            return {
              symbol: stock.symbol,
              beta: stock.beta,
              mktCap: stock.mktCap,
              volAvg: stock.volAvg,
            };
          })} />

Does not produce the expected output, and the table is not shown. I do get the line console.log(sortableItems); printed on the console in the browser, which shows the length of the array is 1 rather then 65


A React component always receives a single props structure, your current naming is misleading. You'd need to access the property you want. E.g. const ProductTable = (props) => { props.products ...

Use spread syntax to declare sortableItems as a copy of items.
// Currently, you declare sortableItems as an array of array:
let sortableItems = [items];

// Instead, you should declare a one-dimensional array by spreading items:
let sortableItems = [...items];

